# How to use wp-ecommerce plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a site that is built in WordPress and I want to add ecommerce functionality. I have some products, and need a backend for these products so I'm using [**wp-ecommerce**](https://wpecommerce.org/) plugin - but how do I use this functionality on frontend?

If anybody has any ideas how to make a shopping related site in WordPress then please let me know.

Comment: Once you have installed and activated the plugin, the front end will sort itself out if you are using the default WordPress theme. If you want a bespoke theme, you'll have to build/download one yourself.

Comment: @Nick Pyett hey nick i have inserted the product using this plugin.Is there is any code which show all product on frontend using the functionality of this plugin

Comment: Which theme are you using? Is it TwentyTen - the default theme? I would also suggest adding some test products, making sure check "Stock Available" and adding an Sku, post name and content (all in a new Post).

Comment: @Nick Pyett hey nick my problem resolved.Thanks

Comment: @Nick Pyett hey nick I have one question

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go straight to the source and talk to the guys that did it

http://www.instinct.co.nz/e-commerce/

and see some video tutorials on the subject

also, you can try different methods, for example, if it's a simple shop why not give [FoxyCart](http://www.foxycart.com/) a go seeing this [**good screencast**](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/56-integrating-foxycart-and-wordpress/) from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/)

or

Comment: Hey Thanks for reply but Iam not able to find the download link for this plugin FoxyCart.

Comment: And also I Think its not free.

Comment: No it's not, as they handle payments and you need to pay for that :) all hassle-free ;)
for Foxy cart, use the screen cast, you will see how to set things up.

Comment: I was just researching foxycart and saw that there is a nice plugin called foxyshop (http://www.foxy-shop.com/). After viewing the video, it seems really promising.